# Export selected rows that have a specified string to a new excel or csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I'm parsing a large excel sheet for specific strings found in one column and need to export those rows found to a new sheet.

I've done the following:
**Selected the file**
BigExcel = r"path to file"

**Created dataframe**
df=pd.read_excel(BigExcel)

**Selected rows with a specific string in a specific column**
df[df["ModuleAndEventText'].str.contains("prtest3")]

Aaaaand now I don't know how to move that output to a new excel or csv file

Comment: `df[df["ModuleAndEventText'].str.contains("prtest3")].to_csv(...)` or `df[df["ModuleAndEventText'].str.contains("prtest3")].to_excel(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the assistance BigBen, but when I append .to_excel(path to file) I'm getting OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\path to file\file.xlsx'  Unfortunately I get the same error when trying it as a CSV.

Comment: Put `r` in front of the string.